# enabling infowindow on cartodb multilayer geoportal map

Tags: javascript, gis, infowindow, cartodb

I've created a [multilayer-geoportal](http://blog.cartodb.com/multilayer-geoportal/) based on that *cartodb* blog post.

I have it up and running and hosted on my *GitHub site*, but I'm trying to enable *infowindows*, and can't get it to work. *Cartodb* support suggested I add in the following line:

```
cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, layer.getSubLayer(0), ['cartodb_id']);
```

after I create the layer. However, when I do that, the map doesn't load at all.

Any suggestions on code that I may be missing in [my github repository](https://github.com/andrewmartini/labs-multilayer/blob/gh-pages/multilayer.js) to fix this problem (line 77 in the multilayer.js file is currently commented out).

To view this live, go to  andrewmartini.github.io/labs-multilayer/multilayer.html?u=andrewmartini&t=multilayer_test&v=0d192f34-2a79-11e5-8e7c-0e4fddd5de28&tt=Title&d=descr

Note:

I'm new to this forum, forgive me if I've broken any posting rules. Also I would add more links but since I'm new, the system won't let me yet. I'm relatively new to using GitHub and Javascript but very familiar with GIS.

Thanks, Andrew

Answer (score 0):

So, this answer from folks at Cartodb was a helpful start, and I wanted to share this for others who are experimenting - the line of code from above needed to go inside the addLayer function:

```
function addLayer(id, show, map) {
    return function (layer) {
        if (!show) {
            layer.hide();
        }
        cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, layer.getSubLayer(0), ['cartodb_id'])
        cartodbLayers[id] = layer;
    };
}
```

And also change this:

```
                cartodb.createLayer(map, layerOptions)
                    .addTo(map)
                    .done(addLayer(id, layer.show, map))
                    .error(function (error) {
                        console.log("error: " + error);
                    });
```

But, this still has issues - for instance if you add other columns to the cbd.vis.Vis.addInfowindow function - only the data layers with that column value will load, and all of the others will fail to load. Can anyone tell me how to fix this so that I can add infowindow for selected columns for multiple datasets from my cartodb account/database?